# Possible variable types in buildout cfg files

Tags: buildout, genshi

Is it possible to define a buildout variable of type dictionary?

I am trying to substitute a variable with a dictionary but buildout considers it a string.

E.g.

in buildout.cfg:

```
[MYPROG]
    progr_args = 
           a : 1 
           b : 2
           d : 
             d1: 1
             d2: 2
```

in template:

```
my_params:
    {% for key, val in parts.MYPROG.progr_args.items() %}\
        ${key}: ${val}\
    {% end %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with Buildout itself, no. Buildout configuration values are always strings; even the [`mr.scripty` recipe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.scripty), which lets you use Python code as part of your buildout configuration, stores the results of the Python code a strings.

Ever worse, initial whitespace from continuation lines is stripped, so your entry:

```
progr_args = 
       a : 1 
       b : 2
       d : 
         d1: 1
         d2: 2
```

is stored as `\na : 1\nb : 2\nd :\nd1: 1\nd2: 2`, having lost all indentation context.

You'll have to use Genshi itself to parse out your values. I suggest you use a separate section:

```
[MYPROG]
prog_params = section_name

[section_name]
a = 1
b = 2
```

and in your template:

```
my_params:
{% for key, val in parts[parts.MYPROG.progr_args].items() %}\
    ${key}: ${val}\
{% end %}
```

Comment: Works for me. Removing the backslash after ${val} will print the options each on a new line.